# How to change .txt character limit to more than 4000 characters in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I Have created one SSIS package using following code

```
select
    ISNULL(LEFT(column1+REPLICATE(' ',15),15) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(column2+REPLICATE(' ',30),30) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(' '+REPLICATE(' ',955),955) ,'')
+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column3+REPLICATE(' ',15),15) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column4+REPLICATE(' ',30),30) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(' '+REPLICATE(' ',955),955) ,'')
+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column5+REPLICATE(' ',15),15) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column6+REPLICATE(' ',30),30) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(' '+REPLICATE(' ',955),955) ,'')
+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column7+REPLICATE(' ',15),15) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column8+REPLICATE(' ',30),30) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(' '+REPLICATE(' ',955),955) ,'')
+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column9+REPLICATE(' ',15),15) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(Column10+REPLICATE(' ',30),30) ,'')
    +ISNULL(LEFT(' '+REPLICATE(' ',955),955) ,'')
FROM table
```

I have to load the data into **.txt** file..
Problem is, the data is loading upto 4000 characters not more than that. 
From the above code data is loading upto column 8 but the data is not loading from column 9.
I have to load the data more than 4000 characters(upto 10000 Characters).. Can you please suggest me which is the best way.

I have tried follwoing ways but the data is not loading...

1: By using data conversion changed data type to **String(DT_STR) Mentioned Length to 8000,text Stream (DT_TEXT)**

2: Changed datatype in Flat file connection manager (in Advanced option) to  **String(DT_STR)Mentioned Length to 8000,text Stream (DT_TEXT)**

Thanks

Comment: You are selecting it but then what are you trying to do with it?  I had similar issue when I was selecting data from a field or a SP with varchar(MAX) over 8000 characters  (or nvarchar(max) over 4000) characters.  I was able to get beyond this by selecting the output into an object variable , and then using c# to  convert the object variable into an SSIS string variable.  It is a weird workaround and depending on what you are trying to do with the results may not be best solution for you, but it fixed my issue (I think it is a known issue but took me a while to find solution for it)

Comment: Do your columns have the datatype `nvarchar(MAX)`? `REPLICATE` won't return a `MAX` datatype unless it is passed one; if it isn't it will truncate the text.

Comment: I had a similar issues without using SSIS that could be solved by forcing a cast and using union, i.e. 
select CAST('*' as varchar(max)) 
union 
select col1+col2+col3+'   '+col4 
from table

Comment: Hi Larnu,
Thank you for the response.. Original Columns have nvarchar(max) i(In table) but not in my code I need columns in fixed length.,.

Comment: If you need fixed width, are you able to change the columns or create a view where you can change the datatype to `char(x)`. That datatype can go up to 8000 characters. If you need to use `nchar()`, it only goes 4000 characters. But they are already fixed width, so you won't have to do the `LEFT(REPLICATE())` thing. But watch out: `char(x)` can balloon your database size, where each field is `x` bytes.

Comment: Also, your `ISNULL()` may be in the wrong place. If one of your `columnX` is `NULL`, then it will result in an empty string instead of the padded string you appear to be creating.

Comment: It feels like you're doing something that SSIS should be doing natively. Could you edit your question with an explanation of what problem you are trying to solve with all the string concatenation?

Comment: If I were using SSIS to generate a fixed-length text file, I'd query the data from SQL Server using a normal SELECT statement and pad each column in the SSIS package, probably via the Derived Column task.

Comment: I replaced Replicate with CHAR(X). It is giving result as i expected @Shawn 
Thank you All

Comment: Just to complete the circle, the "var" in `varchar()` means "variable", so the length of the field will change based on what's in it. If you put a 10 character string in a `varchar(20)`, it will come out as a 10-character sting. But that same 10 characters in a `char(20)` will become a 20-character string with 10 empty characters attached to it. `char()` is what you want to use for fixed-length output files.